# Summation of time series matrix in r

Tags: r

Xt=matrix(1:30, ncol = 3) where t is time period. 
I am trying to Sum from t=1 to 10 solve(t(Xt)%*%Xt)/n).
and I used this code as below.'

`B_hat_T=matrix(NA,p,n)

for (j in 1:n) {
if (j>=p) B_hat_T[,j]<-solve((t(xt[1:j,])%*%xt[1:j,])/n)}`

But it is not working.
Do you have any idea how to fix it?
thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code isn't very clear what you are trying to do (what is n? p?) but two things jump out at me. First, in your code you use `xt` but in the text you use `Xt`. These are different things. Also, `xt` as you defined it in your introduction is exactly singular --- you can't invert it using `solve`. Potentially on topic, using `%*%` and `solve` are probably not the numerically most stable ways of doing that evaluation if that is indeed what you are trying to do.

Secondly, if you make `xt` non-singular

```
xt <- matrix(rnorm(30), ncol = 3)
```

and then run

```
solve((t(xt[1:5, ]) %*% xt[1:5, ]) / 30)
```

the result is a matrix of size 3x3. You can't assign that to a single row of a matrix as you try with `B_hat_T[l j]`.

Finally, if you are trying to just get the column-wise sum of a matrix x for rows 1 through k, something like this:

```
xt <- matrix(1:30, ncol = 3)
k <- 5
apply(xt[1:k, ], 2, sum)
```

will return a vector of the sums of the columns of `xt` for rows 1 to k (in this case, 5). This is the "R way" of doing this. `for` and `if` will take much much longer and more memory to execute.